# XML Keywords not colored in Android Studio in new drawable xml file

Tags: android, xml, drawable, keyword

[image]

I'm making a very basic test app in Android Studio. I am creating an xml file for a button pressed event, but for some reason it is not highlighting any keywords. I have updated android studio. I am at a loss for how to solve this, as it's a new process to me.

The message the lightbulb gives me is "Unexpected text found in layout file" when I try to define these attributes for the bt_pressed XML.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your attribute is nested properly in the tag.  Like this:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/some_color" />
</shape>
```

(hint: look at the `>` character in your provided snippet)

Answer (score 0):

Incorrectly placed ">" in line 2.

Answer (score 0):

I made the rectangle below for a project recently and it worked just fine. Nest it in the in between your first shape tag.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="3dip" />
        <solid android:color="@color/colorTwo" />
    </shape>
</shape>
```

Alternatively, don't nest anything and change your opening shape tag to this:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
```